# Simulate turn by turn navigation in qml map component

Tags: qt, dictionary, navigation, qml, openstreetmap

Basically i made an osm based qml map . i am able to show route on it. Now i need to simulate a point or circle to move along route and whenever it takes a left or right turn a signal needs to be emitted . any pointer to relevant resources is highly appreciated .

Comment: Can't you use the turn by turn navigation instructions provided by GraphHopper or OSRM?

Comment: maybe integrate a web component and something like http://ffwdmejs.org/

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possible approach in QtLocation 5.9:

- define a fencing distance threshold to a maneuver.
- define a distance threshold from the route.

Then build a QGeoPath using the coordinates from your MapRoute, and set the width of the path to be the second threshold above.

Then, at each gps change (maybe you can rate limit this a bit), you check 2 things:

- distance between position and next maneuver less than maneuver threshold. If so, display the maneuver somehow, and then advance to next maneuver.
- distance between position and the route (path.contains()). If you exceed this threshold, you may want to kick of another route calculation, because you ended up off route.